# Why when I run rand() in C at the same time on two machines, I got the same result?

Tags: c, random

When I run the following code at the same time on two different machines, I get the same results. Why they are the same and how I can make them different?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    delay[i] = (rand() % 2000) + 100;
    printf("random number: %i\n", delay[i]);
}
```

the results are the same when I use

```
 srand(time(NULL));
```

My understanding is rand() uses the processor timer to generate random numbers but how can I get rid of that?

Comment: Could you show your entire code?

Comment: You might want to throw something like the result getpid () into the srand call.

Comment: Are you asking what to use as the seed, or are you asking why seeding two random number generators with the same value makes them generate the same results?

Comment: `rand()` returns a deterministic sequence of values for a given seed. The sequence can vary from one implementation to another, but for a given implementation it's always the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Blastfurnace said, the timer() function has a resolution of one second, so that you might solve this problem using a finer resolution. Try it out:

```
struct timeval time; 
gettimeofday(&time,NULL);

srand((time.tv_sec * 1000) + (time.tv_usec / 1000));
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

`srand()` seeds or sets the initial state of the random number generator. I think the problem you are seeing is because `time()` typically only has a resolution of 1 second. It's possible to start the two programs within 1 second of each other so they both get the same starting seed.

You might try using a higher-resolution clock (may not fix the problem) or an OS specific source of randomness for a seed.

Answer (score 1):

The generator is not truly random, it is just running a calculation based on the starting seed and the last retrieved value.  So if you seed the generator with the same value on multiple computers (you just happen to use a clock for the seed, but you could provide a value from any source), you are going to get the same results.  Whether or not the generator uses the processor timer internally is an implementation detail and not a guarantee.

Comment: I think he is confusing "using the processor timer" and "using the current time to seed"

Answer (score 0):

For self-seeding security-grade randomness without modulo-bias use

```
delay[i] = arc4random_uniform( 2000 ) + 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your seed is the same on both machine, then the sequence is the same. Granularity of time is not sufficient. You should try to find another source of randomness. On many modern systems (Unix-like at least) you have a `/dev/random` pseudo-file that you can read to get random bytes. Using it makes very highly non probable to get the same sequence of bytes.